# Qt Gridlayout doesn't realign GUI elements

Tags: c++, qt, qgridlayout

I have the following code in the ctor of my main window widget, in my Qt App.  No matter how I align the buttons added to the QGridLayout, they always stay in the upper left corner, on top of each other.

Can anybody tell me what I've done wrong, I can't find it.

```
btn_File= new QPushButton("&File", this);
btn_Close = new QPushButton("&Close", this);
btn_File->setAutoFillBackground(true);
btn_Close->setAutoFillBackground(true);

QGridLayout * layout = new QGridLayout(this);
layout->setContentsMargins(20,20,10,10);
layout->setSpacing(5);
layout->addWidget(btn_File,2,2, Qt::AlignRight);
layout->addWidget(btn_Close,1,1);
this->setLayout(layout);
```

EDIT: It seems that only the `btn_Close` is being drawn.  I just tried to add a QComboBox to the grid, and it doesn't show up.

Comment: This should work fine. Are you sure you have not used a different layout in the designer?

Comment: @webclectic I'm not using a designer.  I'm doing it all from code, using VS2008.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my main window was derived from `QMainWindow`, in which you need to add a CentralWidget before adding GUI elements.  I changed my main window to derive from `QWidget` instead, and now it works.

Comment: You might add this as a comment to your original post.

Answer (score 0):

tried calling `this->adjustSize()` at the end?

Answer (score 0):

qt layouts really suck! 
alignment on qgridlayout depends on the size of the objects, how many cols an object needs, and the size of the biggest object inserted.. so it is very difficult to put objects as you want...
i suggest to use  setGeometry or move instead!